# Probability a randomly chosen sample of five computer boards contains at least one defective board

Tags: probability

So I have this problem: Five computer boards in a production run of fifty are defective. A sample of five is to be selected to be checked for defects. The probability that a randomly chosen sample of five contains at least one defective board is?

I solved it the way as seen in the picture. The problem is that a friend helped me out with the first part and then I did the math.

I do not understand why I need to do $"1$ - (rest of the problem)"

Why is it $\binom{45}{5}$over $\binom{50}{5}$?

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MCUT.png)

Answer (score 4):

The complement of "at least one" is "there is none", which is much easier to compute.

View $\binom{45}5$ as $$\binom{45}5\cdot \binom50$$

that is choose $5$ from the $45$ good ones and choose none from bad ones.

$\binom{50}{5}$ is the  number of ways to choose $5$ without further restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If $5$ boards are chosen out of $50$, then there can be $0,1,2,3,4$ or $5$ defective boards among them. Let $X$ be the number of defective boards chosen. So, the total probability is:
$$\color{red}{P(X=0)}+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)=\color{blue}{1}.$$
The probability of at least $1$ defective board is:
$$\begin{align}P(X\ge 1)=&P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5) \Rightarrow\\
P(X\ge 1)=&\color{blue}{1}-\color{red}{P(X=0)}\end{align}$$
How do we find $P(X=0)$? Note that if there are $5$ defective boards in total $50$ boards, then the rest $45$ boards must be normal. The number of ways of selecting $5$ normal boards out of $45$ is:
$${45\choose 5}.$$
The number of ways of selecting any $5$ boards out of $50$ is:
$${50\choose 5}.$$
Hence, the probability of selecting $5$ normal boards out of $50$ is:
$$P(X=0)=\frac{{45\choose 5}}{{50\choose 5}}.$$
At last:
$$P(X\ge 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\frac{{45\choose 5}}{{50\choose 5}}.$$